# How to determine an attachment is there or not in WCF service when an user send a mail(either simple text mail or an attachment email)

Tags: c#, wcf

How to determine an attachment is there or not in  WCF service when an user send a mail(either simple text mail or an attachment email) using C#.NET

Comment: Ehm. What about describing your application? How is WCF service related to sending email?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you implemented your mail service, how do you describe an email message when you send it? At a very basic level you would have something like:

```
<MailMessage>
   <Sender>blah@blah.com</Sender>
   <Reciever>blah@blah.com</Reciever>
   <Subject>Some subject here...</Subject>
   <Attatchment>...</Attachement>
   <Message>
       Some message here...
   </Message>
</MailMessage>
```

Using something like this you can easily parse a link to an attatchment and when a user clicks on it they can download the file.